# Calculate the sum of credits per month and different clients

Tags: python, pandas, finance

Currently the dataframe is:

| id_customer | id_credit | duration | date | credit | installment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1001 | 4 | Jan-2-22 | 100 | 25 |
| B | 1002 | 3 | Feb-3-22 | 90 | 30 |
| A | 1003 | 5 | Mar-4-22 | 250 | 50 |

The desired output is:

| id_customer | month | total_sum | total_inv | sum_cred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Feb | 25 | 100-25 | 100 |
| A | Mar | 25 | 100-50 | 350 |
| A | Apr | 25+50 | 350-75-50 | 350 |
| A | May | 25+50 | 350-100-100 | 350 |
| A | Jun | 50 | 250-150 | 250 |
| A | Jul | 50 | 250-200 | 250 |
| A | Ago | 50 | 250-250 | 0 |
| B | Mar | 30 | 90-30 | 90 |
| B | Apr | 30+30 | 90-30-30 | 90 |
| B | May | 30+30+30 | 90-30-30-30 | 0 |

I have tried:

```
creditos = pd.DataFrame({
    "id_customer": ["A", "B", "A"],
    "id_credit":[1001, 1002, 1003],
    "duration": [4,3,5],
    "date": ["2022-01-02", "2022-02-03", "2022-03-04"],
    "credit": [100, 90, 250],
    "installment": [25,30,50],
})

creditos['installment_amount'] = round(creditos['credit'] / creditos['installment'],2)
creditos["date"] = pd.to_datetime(creditos["date"])
creditos['month'] = creditos['date'].dt.to_period('M')

cohort_data = creditos.groupby(['id_customer', 'month'])['credit'].sum().reset_index()
cohort_data2 = cohort_data.groupby(['id_customer', 'month']).sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum().reset_index()
cohort_data = pd.merge(cohort_data, cohort_data2, how='left', on=['id_customer', 'month'])  
cohort_data.columns = ['id_customer', 'month', 'credit', 'sum_cred'] 
cohort_data
```

I get:

| id_customer | month | credit | sum_cred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01 | 100 | 100 |
| A | 2022-03 | 250 | 350 |
| B | 2022-02 | 90 | 90 |

I have no idea how to do the sum per month

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Thank you for including your input, desired output, and code in your question! Could you also please include the actual output of the code you tried?

Comment: Is `client_id` supposed to be `id_customer`? There are also some commas missing in the `creditos` dataframe instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the general pipeline:

```
out = (creditos.assign(month=creditos['date'].dt.to_period('M'))
        # duplicate rows corresponding to the duration
        .loc[creditos.index.repeat(creditos['duration'])]
        # increment months and ensure correct order
        .assign(month=lambda d: d['month']+d.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1))
        .sort_values(by=['id_customer', 'month'])
        # cumulated sum of installments
        .assign(total_sum=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0)['installment'].cumsum())
        # sum per customer
        .groupby(['id_customer', 'month'], as_index=False)
        .agg(**{'total_sum': ('total_sum', 'sum'),
                'sum_cred': ('credit', 'sum'),
               })
        # computation of total_inv and shift of sum_cred
        .assign(total_inv=lambda d: d['sum_cred'].sub(d['total_sum']),
                sum_cred=lambda d: d.groupby('id_customer')['sum_cred'].shift(-1, fill_value=0)
               )
       )
```

Output:

```
  id_customer    month  total_sum  sum_cred  total_inv
0           A  2022-02         25       100         75
1           A  2022-03         50       350         50
2           A  2022-04        125       350        225
3           A  2022-05        200       250        150
4           A  2022-06        150       250        100
5           A  2022-07        200       250         50
6           A  2022-08        250         0          0
7           B  2022-03         30        90         60
8           B  2022-04         60        90         30
9           B  2022-05         90         0          0
```